# How to read selected column from a .tsv file?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a .tsv file

```
Frequencies   Intensities
-350.51 13.7712
54.8965 0.298093
63.7786 8.16809
134.198 1.66818
144.028 2.19037
148.808 1.13914
167.588 7.58799
185.603 4.63792
206.212 1.04249
229.086 6.38628
239.265 7.7888
277.323 8.31206
298.328 18.5049
593.467 0.100776
642.199 0.0708063
685.177 0.570148
730.67  11.1965
732.848 2.5357
830.964 22.6193
856.667 4.94958
1043.11 5.80368
1134.92 13.664
1306.82 31.9118
1331.34 58.0725
1518.05 89.9757
1702.15    100
3800.18 11.8662
```

I want to read the first column from 2nd to last row and use the numbers to get an array like this

```
w112161617 = np.array([
54.8965,
63.7786,
134.198,
144.028,
148.808,
167.588,
185.603,
206.212,
229.086,
239.265,
277.323,
298.328,
593.467,
642.199,
685.177,
730.67,
732.848,
830.964,
856.667,
1043.11,
1134.92,
1306.82,
1331.34,
1518.05,
1702.15,
3800.18
])
```

please inform how to do that.

I tried to do this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = '/Users/chirantan/Desktop/12161617b.tsv'
b_data=pd.read_table(b)
b_data.head()
```

which prints the whole tsv file like this

```
Frequencies     Intensities
0   -350.5080   13.798800
1   54.9287     0.299525
2   63.7058     8.166240
3   134.1750    1.668960
4   144.0070    2.191290
```

but it is also printing only upto 6th row.

I need all rows of 1st column except the negative number (2nd row) and the headings (1st row).

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_table` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21948). Use `read_csv` instead:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/chirantan/Desktop/12161617b.tsv', sep='\\t', engine='python')

frequencies = df.loc[df['Frequencies'] >= 0, 'Frequencies'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

`b_data['Frequencies']`
will get you all of first column.

`b_data[b_data['Frequencies'] >= 0]`
will get you all of the dataframe without negative numbers.

`b_data[b_data['Frequencies'] >= 0]['Frequencies']`
will get you all of the first column without negative numbers.